# How to make an activities stream mixing posts and comments?

Tags: wp-query, query, wpdb, sql

What I'm currently trying to make is an activities stream wich list :

- The posts,
- the comments,
- both mixed between them and ordered by date.

My idea is to make two queries, but i don't know how to mix them up. Here are my queries :

```
// Query the posts :
$queryPosts = "
    SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'post'
    AND post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY post_date DESC
";

// Query the comments :
$queryComments = "
    SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments
    ORDER BY comment_date DESC
";
```

Is that possible with some kind of SQL JOIN ?

**UPDATE:**
I tried what was suggested by @scribu about using SQL UNION and it's working well :

```
SELECT ID AS entry_id, post_date AS entry_date, post_content AS entry_content FROM $wpdb->posts
WHERE post_type = 'post'
AND post_status = 'publish'
UNION
SELECT comment_ID AS entry_id, comment_date AS entry_date, comment_content AS entry_content FROM $wpdb->comments
ORDER BY entry_date DESC
```

What I'm trying to do now is access some data which are in the posts table and not in the comments table. Any idea ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: How many of each do you want? Do you want reverse chronological? What attributes of each do you want/need? Permalink, Excerpt? More?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - "How many of each do you want?" I don't want to limit the result. "Do you want reverse chronological?" Yes. "What attributes of each do you want/need?" I just tried what was suggested by @scribu about using SQL UNION and it's working well but as you ask I have now some news problems about the data that I would like to be able to retrieve. For example I would like to access the "comment_count" which is in the posts table but doesn't have any equivalent in the comments table.

Comment: I you have an additional question please [ask another question here on the WPSE site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [SQL UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I updated my post. My next problem is: Each result is display in a div, I would like to be able to add a class with the type of result for each. For example: Each comment get a class="comment" and each post get a class="post". Any idea ?

Comment: Sure, just add `post_type AS entry_type` and `'comment' AS entry_type` columns and then check it when doing the output.

Comment: You can use the same trick for the comment count:

`comment_count` and `0 AS comment_count` respectively.